# Eclipse missing Plugins after Fedora 34 upgrade - Error on reinstalling

Tags: java, eclipse, fedora

Yesterday I upgraded to Fedora 34. Today I realized that my Eclipse is missing all its plugins. I had a similar issue with my last upgrade and fixed it be reinstalling all plugins. But this time I always get these kinds of errors:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.ibm.icu,65.1.0
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.sun.jna,5.4.0
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.sun.jna.platform,5.4.0
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.batik.constants,1.13.0
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.batik.css,1.13.0
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.batik.i18n,1.13.0
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.batik.util,1.13.0
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.codec,1.13.0
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.apache.commons.io,2.6.0
```

I already removed all the available software sites in the preferences and deleted the .eclipse folder in my home directory. That sadly didn't help. What do I have to do?

Version: 2021-03 (4.19) Build id: X20210311-1732

Comment: What version of Eclipse is this? I don't know of any release that uses ICU 65.1 and JNA 5.4

Comment: Version: 2021-03 (4.19)
Build id: X20210311-1732

Comment: The X prefix on the Build Id is not a normal Eclipse prefix (should be P, M, I, S, or R). Where did this build come from?

Comment: I installed it using dnf install eclipse as shown here: https://developer.fedoraproject.org/tools/eclipse/about.html

Comment: That seems only the Eclipse SDK (without Git, Maven, etc). Better get an [official Eclipse IDE package](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/). Also available via [Flathub](https://flathub.org/apps/details/org.eclipse.Java).

Comment: That, or the Fedora packages have been reorganized and you need to see what other `eclipse-*` packages are available and should be installed using `dnf search eclipse`.

Comment: @nitind I just tried out multiple of these eclipse packages that sounded like they could be related but that sadly didn't fix the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did some digging. As mentioned in [this](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Fedora-Java-Rough-Shape) article Red Hat has some problems in maintaining Maven-related packages. Probably the Eclipse package won't be part of Fedora 35 anymore.

I tried using Flathub as advised in the comments under my question by @howIger but ran into some problems with the sandbox of Flathub. I debug my application directly in docker and Flathub has no access to the /usr folder which was necessary for my case.

So in the end I installed Eclipse from source as described in [this](https://tecadmin.net/install-eclipse-fedora/) older article.